# FInding out which object is eating up memory in Android App

Tags: android

In the Android App I wrote, memory usage seems to be high. The App gets slower and slower the more time you keep using it. So, am trying to dig out the cause, using DDMS in Eclipse. This is what I see in the 'Heap' tab in DDMS when I click 'cause GC':

[image]

sorry, am new to this ; I admit. Cannot make anything out of it. There is that one object '1-byte array' using more than 6MB (!!) of space. How do I get its stack trace? How do I find where is this object being created?

To brief on when this GC was done (I clciked 'cause GC' button in DDMS): the App has a background thread which contacts a remote server once every few seconds. This heap was taken during one such time, well after the App had begun (and no interaction by the user yet).

Can someone please help?

Comment: it's probably a bitmap. Why are you so worried ?

Comment: @Blackbelt , how do you say it's a Bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a programming problem but an engineering problem.

You should be able to see the memory usage across Activity. That means you know which Activity consumes the memory.

Inside that Activity, try to comment out suspicious code and see the difference. Very probably the memory is consumed in image or video. So I suggest you keep an eye on decoding bitmap or setting video URL to VideoView.

Comment: how do you "track" the memory usage ? How can I say where is this 6MB object (that I see in the screenshot) being created?

Comment: When does the memory consumption occur? Say, upon onCreate of a certain Activity? or after a onClick?

Comment: the App has a background thread which contacts a remote server once every few seconds. This heap was taken during one such time, well after the App had begun (and no interaction by the user yet).

Comment: To confirm the problem occur inside that thread, try to not running it upon app start and see whether the memory is still consumed. If so, the problem is at that thread